# how make button alignment responsive in css?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to place the button at the bottom left side. The alignment should be responsive.
Below is my html code:

```css
.third-banner {
  /*background-image: url("banner3.PNG");*/
  background-image: url("banner3new.JPG");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
}

.banner-btn {
  border-radius: 17px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 600px;
  margin-right: 350px;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.banner-btn:hover {
  background-color: #1492ed;
  border-block-color: #1492ed;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="third-banner">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger banner-btn">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>
</center>
```

[image: Refer this image. The red button is what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: could you please explain more? I didn't get what you mean

Comment: `<center>` is obsolete. It a tag from HTML4. Any HTML5 approach (excluding HTML4 emails) should use CSS instead!

Comment: "*The alignment should be responsive.*" - in what way? What do you want it to do, in response to what? Incidentally, white text on a white background - your demo - is inaccessible; remember that your [MCVE] code needs to be adequately representative of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.third-banner {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/20/800/600");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90%;
}

.banner-btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.banner-btn:hover {
  background-color: #1492ed;
  border-block-color: #1492ed;
}
```

```html
<div class="third-banner">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger banner-btn">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
```

If you position:absolute your button not in a relative div, it'll be absolute of body.

Answer (score 0):

give the parent container position:relative it will work